# How to compare two html files and show only the differences in a new html file using python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-2.7, difflib

I have used difflib but the html_table line is taking forever to execute.

```
import difflib

html_1 = data1
html_2 = data2

htmldiff = difflib.HtmlDiff()
html_table = htmldiff.make_table([html_1], [html_2])
```

I have tried htmldiffer but it is giving me ValueError: stat: path too long for Windows

```
from htmldiffer import diff

str_a = data1
str_b = data2
d = diff.HTMLDiffer(data1, data2)

print(d.combined_diff)
```

I have tried htmltreediff it is giving NameError: name 'basestring' is not defined

```
from htmltreediff import diff
print (diff(data1, data2 , pretty=True))
```

Comment: Could you also provide full error trace?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to make long file paths available on windows:
https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/

CPython issues related to difflib:

- http://bugs.python.org/issue6931: dreadful performance in difflib:
  ndiff and HtmlDiff http://bugs.python.org/issue11740: difflib html
  diff takes extremely long

> Solution for long chunks would be to split them into smaller parts and
>   process separately. This way quadratic time will be smaller and we
>   still can benefit from _fancy_helper logic.

`htmltreediff` - does not support python 3

Comment: I have followed "This is how to make long file paths available on windows" steps and made changes .Still it is showing the same error.

Comment: @Sushmitha have u restarted your pc?